# Android - run JUnit tests before connectedAndroidTest

Tags: android, gradle

I like to have one singe task that will do following thing -

1. it will first run all `JUnit` tests(i.e. tests under `src/test/java`).
2. then it will run all `Instrumented` tests (i.e. tests under `src/androidTest/java`)

How can I do that? I am using Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sequential, but can be combined into a single task, like follows -

```
task combindTest{

    dependsOn "testDebugUnitTest", "connectedDebugAndroidTest"
}
```